# Symfony2 updating bootstrap.php.cache

Tags: symfony

Recently I started a project in Symfony2 from the BETA version available on symfony.com

After a while, I needed to upgrade to the master branch, so I retrieved the latest from github and switched it in vendor/symfony.

However, my bootstrap.php.cache and bootstrap_cache.php.cache are not upgraded, which has generated errors.

I tried clearing the symfony cache, to no avail.

How can I update these files to correspond to my project?

Comment: see my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919275/strange-doctrine-entitynotfoundexception/31664345#31664345

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In the 2.0 release the original file is here:

```
./vendor/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

Edit: in release 2.3 the file is here

```
vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to do anything in my project when I run the above script (this is also after I updated my vendors' bundles). Any ideas on troubleshooting this?

Comment: @Eno did you try removing (make a backup first) the bootstap cache files and then running the script?

Comment: `composer update` is all you need now (Symfony 2.3 + Composer)

Comment: `composer update` also updates the dependencies that is not what **jihi** asked for! please check my answer. it shows how it should be done: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26337973/828366

Comment: For 2.3 (and 3.0) it's now `php vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php`

Answer (score 66):

If you run the `composer update` command you will also update your project dependencies which is not the desired behaviour here. If you do that you'll have to test the new changes to see if they do affect your application somehow.

So if you just want to rebuild your bootstrap cache file then I suggest you run the **post-update-cmd** command.

Therefore you should use:

```
composer run-script post-update-cmd
```

which in my case executes the following scripts (see **composer.json**):

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrapSass"
    ]
}
```

Please consider that you can also create a new set of scripts in there to just rebuild the bootstrap file and clears the cache without installing the assets and so on:

```
"scripts": {
    "reset-bootstrap-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache"
    ]
}
```

and then... `composer run-script reset-bootstrap-cmd`

Comment: best answer for symfony >=2.3

Answer (score 28):

In the latest 2.1.0-DEV, the actual script is here:

`./vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php`

Comment: For current 2.1 `composer update` takes care of it - scripts array is added to composer configuration

Comment: @barius Only for out of the box Composer scripts, which e.g. I didn't have.

Answer (score 22):

I'm using Symfony Standard 2.0.9 (without Vendors).

To update `bootstrap.php.cache`, just run

`php bin/vendors update`

This will update all vendors (including Symfony itself) and always call that `build_bootstrap.php` script for you.

Comment: Indeed, `composer update` triggers the "build bootstrap" script. This is the current up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 17):

Have you tried running:

```
php bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

This will regenerate the bootstrap files

Comment: Didn't know that was there. Thanks!

Comment: Worth to mention, that this doesn't work anymore. The whole `bin/`-folder is gone now.

Comment: In fact, this file is not available even in latest 2.0

Comment: Now, `build_bootstrap.php` is a bit hidden... `php ./vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php`

Answer (score 11):

You might prefer to use `composer install` which "re-installs" the system to the state definied in the `composer.lock` file and generates autoloads and bootstrap.php.cache. Using `composer update` updates all packages and changes the state of your system.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like the build_bootstrap script is always changing location :)

So, if you are working with several Symfony versions and don't know where the build_bootstrap is, this will do the trick (Linux/Mac only):

```
$ cd vendor/ 
$ find . -name build_bootstrap.php
```

Comment: Never remember the exact name, so every time I have to type this command. `find . -iname "*build*bootstrap*php"`

Answer (score 1):

i couldnt fix a problem on my bootstrap cache, nor update it . i was getting alot of this

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>     Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/sites/fuji/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2870
>
> Script
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
>   handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

although they were great suggestions, and i did try the rebuilding of bootstrap cache file after backing it up, and to run `composer update` these still gave me the same problem.

Solution for me:
i shelled into the pc with the site files on it, 
`rm -rf app/cache/* -R`  removed everything inside the cache directory then i was able to run both composer update, AND clear cache etc.. with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Search for where the "build_bootstrap.php" located at.

for my case  in *Symfony3.4*

```
php ./vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```