# Clone a Symfony2 project

Tags: git, symfony

Im cloning a Git repo from our server.
When I do so files from the gitignore are missing, obviusly.
And like this page says, http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html, the folder/files that should be ignored are:

```
/web/bundles/
/app/bootstrap*
/app/cache/*
/app/logs/*
/vendor/
/app/config/parameters.yml
```

But then how to install all the bundles etc. Im trying to run `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug` and it obviusly gives an error since there are files missing.

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(/Users/david/Sites/cliico/app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/david/Sites/cliico/app/console on line 10
```

PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/Users/david/Sites/cliico/app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php/pear') in /Users/david/Sites/cliico/app/console on line 10

There must be an easy way to recreate those folders that the people from Symfony2 reccomend to ignore.

Thanks

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072081/symfony2-updating-bootstrap-php-cache

Answer (score 4):

### **Symfony > 2.1** (composer)

You need to install composer at the root of your project

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Then do `php composer.phar install` it will download all vendors defined in composer.json and add them to the folder /vendors

### **For Symfony 2.0.*** (deps)

You have deps file, use :

> php bin/vendors install

Comment: try php bin/vendors install

Comment: I tried and I get, PHP Warning:  parse_ini_file(/Users/david/Sites/cliico/deps): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/david/Sites/cliico/bin/vendors on line 74
The deps file is not valid ini syntax. Perhaps missing a trailing newline?

Comment: Could you please add your deps file and Symfony version

Comment: The content of the deps file is:
IvoryCKEditorBundle ef9a9bac52f5fb823b6b670074702b9591c9ad87
Only one line, and the version Im using is Symfony2