# Generating Phpunit skeletons test classes in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I got my phpunit test in symfony though I am trying to use PhpUnit skelgen to generate skeleton for my test classes. I had a look at the PhpUnit [documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/skeleton-generator.html)

```
phpunit-skelgen --test -- "project\Calculator" Calculator.php
```

My path for the file i want to generate skeleton is:

```
Boltmail\UserBundle\BoltmailFactory\UserLoginFactory.php
```

and following the documentation i have inserted the following:

```
./bin/phpunit-skelgen --test -- "Boltmail\UserBundle\BoltmailFactory\UserLoginFactory" UserLoginFactory.php
```

And this keeps on throwing InvalidArgumentException:

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]                                                      
  Command "Boltmail\UserBundle\BoltmailFactory\UserLoginFactory" is not defined.
```

Any idea guys where i am going wrong with all the before you ask yes i have installed phpunit and phpunit-skelgen through my composer.json

OK After a suggestion in a below answer i changed my terminal command to this:

```
./bin/phpunit-skelgen --bootstrap app\bootstrap.php.cache --test -- "Boltmail\UserBundle\BoltmailFactory\UserLoginFactory"
```

Now I get this error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                        
  Command "appbootstrap.php.cache" is not defined.
```

Before all these i did:

composer update which installed bootstrap/php/cache under app/ dir

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

`--bootstrap app\bootstrap.php.cache` to arguments for `phpunit-skelgen`

Comment: hmm why would not this be mentioned in Docs any reasons...?

Comment: and under my app/ dir i do not have a bootstrap.php.cache files.

Comment: which symfony2 version you have? Try runing `php bin/vendors update` and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072081/symfony2-updating-bootstrap-php-cache if you have symfony > 2.3 and composer then run `composer update`

Comment: OK thats a start, after composer update the file 'bootstrap.php.cach' appeared under app directory. What do I need to do from here...?

Comment: from here you need do what I wrote in my answer :)

Comment: try change `--bootstrap app\bootstrap.php.cache` for `--bootstrap app/bootstrap.php.cache`