# Symfony startup

Tags: php, eclipse, symfony

I need help with creating a symfony project in ubuntu/eclipse i get a lot of warnings. i Use:

ubuntu: 15.04
eclipse: 4.5.0 mars
symfony feature: 1.1.0.20150705

I use Symfony Feature to create projects using a built in wizard.
Project details:

PHP version: 5.6
Symfony version: v2.7.3
Override composer.jason values: i use defaults

i get errors with app/bootstrap.php.cache

Maybe there is a good tutorial that might help me, but 'till now i haven't found one...
Maybe elipse isn't good for symfony project.

Here are some error messages:

```
!ENTRY com.dubture.composer.core 4 4 2015-08-06 20:49:38.196
!MESSAGE PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/test3/app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/test3/app/console on line 10
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/test3/app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/test3/app/console on line 10
```

and second

```
!ENTRY com.dubture.composer.core 4 4 2015-08-06 20:50:29.267
!MESSAGE Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.7.2)
  - Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.7.2)
    Loading from cache
Created project in test1
> SymfonyStandard\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.5 -> satisfiable by sensiolabs/security-checker[v2.0.5].
    - sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.5 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.5 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - sensio/distribution-bundle v4.0.0 requires sensiolabs/security-checker ~2.0 -> satisfiable by sensiolabs/security-checker[v2.0.5].
    - Installation request for sensio/distribution-bundle v4.0.0 -> satisfiable by sensio/distribution-bundle[v4.0.0].
```

thats a piece of the whole log file, those are the messages i get in gui.

Comment: I would recommend posting some of the actual error messages otherwise it will be difficult (to impossible) to troubleshoot your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Composer installation failed with an error (see second set of error messages) because it could not install all dependencies.

It says in the error message:

```
the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
```

You need to install this extension for PHP to get all required files to get your project up and running.

Comment: Isn't there a manual for configuring eclipse for symfony ? i've installed
php5-curl i dont have that bootstrap error but now i have 6 new errors and 228 warnings...

Answer (score 1):

When Symfony2 starts up, it need some of bootstrap cookies which will be removed, eventually. From my experience, 'bootstrap.php.cache' file existed for ACME bundle example pages, and It is not essential file.

The solution is simple.
You just need to create 'bootstrap.php.cache' file in /var/www/test3/app/ folder. **The content of 'bootstrap.php.cache' can be blank.**

```
touch bootstrap.php.cache
```

Hope this works well for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that, you don't have right permission for read in these file, check this sudo chmod 755 in these file. If you haven't that file, create it how suggests YONGSOO KIM

> The solution is simple. You just need to create bootstrap.php.cache
>   file in /var/www/test3/app/ folder. The content of bootstrap.php.cache
>   can be blank.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix problem with versions of package `sensiolabs/security-checker` or generate bootstrap cache file like answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6884027/4356973