# Symfony project works on live server but not on wamp

Tags: symfony, wamp

I am assigned a symfony project. It is my first project, so I transfered the symfony files from live server to local wamp (win 7) in order to do some tests. While the site works in live and demo server ( I transfered it by myself) in my local wamp it throws error 500. So I suppose there is a problem with my server and not the project itself. php log file shows nothing. Also I have enabled rewrite module, php accelerator and minimum requirements are met. How can I debug it? I would like to give more info but unfortunately I can't even find what causes error 500... Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: on which env you are running your website?
dev or prod?

Comment: The live server runs in what OS ? Windows or unix ?

Comment: The live server runs on linux. Concerning the environment  I try to run it both from web/app_dev.php and web/app.php (I dont know if that's answers ur question) but the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
composer run-script post-update-cmd
```

See this : [Symfony2 updating bootstrap.php.cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072081/symfony2-updating-bootstrap-php-cache)

Your bootstrap.php.cache was build on UNIX and won't work in Windows + it contains absolute paths.

Comment: Yes, in the root director